# How to parsing Json in AWS Athena?

Tags: python, sql, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to parse the JSON column in Athena but I have a problem in one column.  The column includes an escape character. I don't know if this problem. I want to reach to Message. You can see below sample data and Message under Return. Thanks

```
Sample Code 
CAST(json_extract_scalar(callparameters, '$return.Message') AS VARCHAR) AS Message
```

This is the JSON.

```
{"inputs":{"usagespecid":"null","playsessionid":"null","satellitetypecd":"\"ERU\"","channelcontentid":"231"},
"return":"{\"Message\":\"Do not person you have called \"}"}    {"date":"2021-07-26","epoch":"1627"}    {"userpartyid":"23","userloginkey":"23","usercountrycode":"br","sessionkey":"23","client":{"name":"SMR","id":"1"},"usermainsatellitetype":"DS","userserviceaccountids":["23"],"usergeolocationid":"53","userpartyroleid":"76"}
```

Comment: This is not a valid json. Is it an array? Are those different rows? Can you please fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take only the object which contains `return` you can parse `return` into json with [`json_parse`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse) since it contains an encoded string not an json object:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES          
       (JSON '{
   "inputs":{
      "usagespecid":"null",
      "playsessionid":"null",
      "satellitetypecd":"\"ERU\"",
      "channelcontentid":"231"
   },
   "return":"{\"Message\":\"Do not person you have called \"}"
}')
 ) AS t (json_string))


SELECT json_extract_scalar(json_parse(json_extract_scalar(json_string, '$.return')), '$.Message')
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| Do not person you have called |